# Как в одном потоке получить данные из других потоков?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, очередь

Вот мой код, который иллюстрирует проблему:

```
from threading import Thread
import queue
import time

q = queue.Queue()


class Worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        if self.name == '0':
            update_tasks()
        else:
            while True:
                task = q.get()
                result = do_work(task)
                if not result:
                    q.put(task)
                
            
def update_tasks():
    while True:
        tasks = set(get_new_tasks()) - set(get_completed_tasks) - set(list(q.queue))
        for task in tasks:
            q.put(task)
        time.sleep(10)


def run_threads():
    threads = []
    for i in range(15):
        my_thread = Worker(str(i))
        my_thread.start()
        threads.append(my_thread)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

run_threads()
```

Я запускаю 15 потоков.
Из них 1 поток я отправляю пополнять количество задач функцией `update_tasks()`
А остальные 14 должны решать эти задачи функцией `do_work()`
Новые задачи поступают каждые 10 секунд.
При этом, в свежеполученных задачах постоянно приходят те, что уже выполнены.
Поэтому функция `update_tasks()` сравнивает свежеполученные задачи с теми, что уже сделаны, и теми, что находятся сейчас в очереди.

А теперь сама проблема:
`do_work()` решает задачу примерно за 1 минуту и `14` задач, которые сейчас в работе снова поступают в список новых задач. Потому что они еще не появились в списке решенных задач. Но и в `q.queue` их уже нет.
Эта конструкция их пропускает:

```
asks = set(get_new_tasks()) - set(get_completed_tasks) - set(list(q.queue))
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно одним потоком получить задачи, которые в это время выполняют другие потоки, для того чтобы избежать повторного выполнения одних и тех же задач?

Comment: Может попробуешь драматик или селери? Все таки готовые решения для организации очереди задач. А так, в твоем псевдо брокере должно быть 3 набора: задачи готовые к исполнению, задачи в процессе исполнения, выполненные задачи. Каждая задача отдается работнику и ожидается что работник вернет ответ в течение N времени, если он этого не сделал, то задача публикуется повторно. Каждый работник должен отчитываться брокеру о том что он закончил. Примерно...

Comment: @alex А что быстрее в освоении. Драматик или Селери? Мне чем проще, тем лучше.

Comment: Наверное драматик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

исходя из вашего кода, зачем вообще проверять выполнение задач в воркерах, не проще ли делать это в update_tasks, она ведь и так знает что отправляла воркерам, а безрезультатные task добавляет сам воркер

```
def update_tasks():
    _tasks = set()  # ожидающие выполнения или уже выполненные task

    while True:
        tasks = get_new_tasks() - _tasks  # только новые task

        if tasks:
            _tasks.update(tasks)
            for task in tasks:
                q.put(task)
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. Я приблизительно так и сделал. Но так-же я понял, что лучше не изобретать велосипед на костылях, по этому начал знакомится с брокерами задач.